How could I draw child div below parent div in css?
consider such a jsx code
    <>
      <div className="outer-div">
       <div className="inner-div">
       </div>
      </div>
    </>

and the following css
.outer-div {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.inner-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  top: -25px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 16px 16px 0 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

it looks like this

but I want it to be drawn like this (rounded borders below cause of the "overlap")

And I want it to be drawn with only 2 divs. Is it possible? I tried to change positions to relative and changed z-indexes with no luck.
